# How do you find the change of coordinates matrix from a given matrix to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: matrix]

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  The examples I've come across on the internet show how to find the change of coordinates matrix from a matrix to another matrix, such as B to C (for example).

I came up with an answer but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I started out with the matrix with those three vectors mentioned above:

```
3    2    1
0    2   -2
6   -4    3
```

Then I found the inverse which is the following:

```
1/21    5/21     1/7
2/7    -1/14    -1/7
2/7    -4/7     -1/7
```

Then I multiplied by the standard basis of a 3x1 vector:

```
1/21    5/21     1/7         1
2/7    -1/14    -1/7    *    0
2/7    -4/7     -1/7         0
```

And came up with the following answer:

```
1/21
2/7
2/7
```

Is this correct?  Something tells me I'm missing something or perhaps I approached the whole thing incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you understand what it means to write a vector $v$ in the basis $B$.  In the standard basis, $S$, the vector $(1,2,3)_S$ is the linear combination
$$1\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right] + 2\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right] + 3\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right] $$ which is the same as the matrix multiplication problem: $$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right].$$

In the basis $B$, the vector $(1,2,3)_B$ is the linear combination
$$1\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}3\\0\\6\end{array}\right] + 2\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}2\\2\\-4\end{array}\right] + 3\cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\-2\\3\end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 3&0&6\\2&2&-4\\1&-2&3 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right].$$

In general, a the matrix $T$ of a basis can be used to change a vector $v_T$ in the basis to the standard basis $S$  via $T\cdot v_T = v_S$.

(This agrees with the fact that $I\cdot v_S = v_S$.)

In this case, a vector represented in both $S$ and $B$ would satsify $B\cdot v_B = I \cdot v_S$ and $v_B = B^{-1} \cdot v_S$.

This shows how $B$ and $B^{-1}$ are the matrices to go back and forth from $B$ to the standard basis.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix which changes coordinates with respect to the basis $B$ to the coordinates with respect to the standard basis $B^{\prime}$ is given by

$P=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 2 & -2\\ 6 & -4 & 3\end {pmatrix}$ whose columns are just the vectors in $B$.

To get the matrix which changes coordinates from $B^{\prime}$ to $B$, just take $P^{-1}$.

---

In general, if $B=\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ and $B^{\prime}=\{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$ are two bases for a vector space,

the change of coordinate matrix from $B$ to $B^{\prime}$ is given by

$\begin{bmatrix} [v_1]_{B^{\prime}} \;\vert & \cdots &\vert\;\;  [v_n]_{B^{\prime}} \end{bmatrix}$.